# add data to list view in android without clear old data

Tags: android, list, view

add data to list view in android without clear old data

I use this code:
ListView listRecommended = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewAppsFree);
            listRecommended.setAdapter(new AppsListAdapter(CategoryActivity.this,names,icons,ratings,prices));

I want to add new data without refresh old data or clear old data in `listveiw`?

how to do it?

replace `setadapter` with what?

example :
list view data:
a
b
c

add new data in last view

a old data
b old data
c old data
d new data

plz show in example code

Comment: but `ListView.setadapter` method take only one parameter as DataSource and currently you are passing two parameters?

Comment: you might need to add data to your existing adapter and refresh the view...think this works

Comment: You will have to refresh the adapter attached to the `listview` in order to show up the new results you added.

Answer (score 0):

Add your data to objects array (or map) that adapter uses.
Then just call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
That will redraw list if items in adapter were changed.

**Updated:**
Change assignment adapter to your listView this way:

```
ListView listRecommended = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewAppsFree);
AppsListAdapter adapter = new AppsListAdapter(CategoryActivity.this,names,icons,ratings,prices);
listRecommended.setAdapter(adapter);
```

For example, you can create button with OnClickListener implementation in onCreate or OnCreateView methods of your Activity/Fragment class:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_update_button);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // add some data to your adapter first just puching new object to names, icons, etc. arrays you're using in your adapter;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
});
```

Comment: my code is ListView listRecommended = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewAppsFree);
   listRecommended.setAdapter(new AppsListAdapter(CategoryActivity.this,names,icons,ratings,prices));

Comment: I add adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); but when run it,not working

Comment: Did you add new data in adapter before notifying it for updating list?

Comment: yes with : AppsListAdapter adapter = new AppsListAdapter(CategoryActivity.this,names,icons,ratings,prices);    then adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: That's wrong.
Use existing adapter. Just data via adapter.add(obj); method. Just define adapter as class field.

Comment: but adapter.add not valid and wrong in Syntex in eclips!?show error not defined in AppListAdapter